# ZSH Magic for certain exit-status situations

Tags: perl, zsh

Hey I thought about writing a function that prompts me in certain situations (perl had a bad exit status and the warning it prints starts with "Could not find *** in @INC) with maybe re-running the command.

Do you think this is feasable?

I have found that `TRAPZERR` function. but i don't even get the name of the last command in there, only the last argument, so one concrete point would be: how can I get the command-name out of it?  `!!:0` doesn't work.

Next thing is: i think i might have to do some tricks with preexec to catch the first line of the stderr (if that doesn't work that's not a big problem, but it would be interesting anyway), I thought about appending an 2> to a pipe or something but I'm not sure how to get that pipe constructed in the first place. But as stated above, this is a minor issue.

But really, if you think: No this task is impossible! Please tell me so (although I would be interested why).

From the one answer i got until now I think i can narrow down the problem a little:

Is it possible to wrap a MULTIOS redirection around a perl script? ( I thought about some special kind of exec, but came up with none that worked)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start.

```
preexec() {
  lastcommand=$1
  exec 3>&1 4>&2                   
  exec 2> >(tee /tmp/output 1>&4)
}
precmd() {
  read line </tmp/output
  case "$line" in
  "Can't locate"*)
    echo "Perl module missing running $lastcommand"
    ;;
  esac
}
```

But maybe you want to do something at the language level like [How can I hook into Perl's use/require so I can throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869067/how-can-i-hook-into-perls-use-require-so-i-can-throw-an-exception)

Comment: thanks, I'll try it out! Nope I definitly don't want it on the language level, that's the whole point, I want to query myself if I want to cpaninstall the module, and not some checks at compile time.

Comment: but why aren't you useing TRAPZERR, seems more reasonable to me as it only gets executed if a program had a bad exit status.